# Apparent indices limit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Using SceneKit in swift I trying to build a custom 3D object (a terrain). To build a terrain I build a plane that I've divided in a number of horizontal and vertical section. With a small number or section everything is fine but with not so large number the app crash in some deep OpenGL function with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Here is a simplified version of the terrain (yes it's just a plane) which don't exhibit the issue:

```
let width:Float = 12
let depth:Float = 12
let height:Float = 2
let nx = 6
let nz = 6

func build() -> SCNGeometry {
    var vertices : [SCNVector3] = Array()
    for i in 0..<(nx + 1) {
        for j in 0..<(nz + 1) {
            let x = (Float(i) / Float(nx)) * width - width/2
            let z = (Float(j) / Float(nz)) * depth - depth/2
            let y = Float(0)
            vertices.append(SCNVector3(x:x, y:y, z:z))
        }
    }

    var indices : [CInt] = []
    for i in 0..<nx {
        for j in 0..<nz {
            indices.append(CInt(i   + j * (nz+1)))
            indices.append(CInt(i+1 + j * (nz+1)))
            indices.append(CInt(i   + (j+1)*(nz+1)))

            indices.append(CInt(i+1 + j * (nz+1)))
            indices.append(CInt(i+1 + (j+1)*(nz+1)))
            indices.append(CInt(i   + (j+1)*(nz+1)))
        }
    }

    let data = NSData(bytes: vertices, length: sizeof(SCNVector3) * countElements(vertices))

    let vertexSource = SCNGeometrySource(data: data, semantic: SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex, vectorCount: vertices.count, floatComponents: true, componentsPerVector: 3, bytesPerComponent: sizeof(Float), dataOffset: 0, dataStride: sizeof(SCNVector3))

    let indexData = NSData(bytes: indices, length: sizeof(CInt) * countElements(indices))

    let element = SCNGeometryElement(data: indexData, primitiveType: SCNGeometryPrimitiveType.Triangles, primitiveCount: indices.count, bytesPerIndex: sizeof(CInt))

    return SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource], elements: [element])
}
```

Now change nx and nz to:

```
let nx = 8
let nz = 8
```

*Crash*

This seems very much linked with the number of indices but at ~300 I don't believe I should be hitting a limit.

Any suggestion, help or solution very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How many vertices at the time of the crash? What line (in your code, if any) does the crash occur in? Call stack?

Comment: My mistake the crash seem to be linked with the number of **indices**. I'll edit my description.

With nx=nz=8 the terrain is made of 384 indices (8*8*6). With nx=nz=7 I don't get any crash, that's 294 indices. So no obvious power of 2.

The stack trace is in the OpenGL rendering logic, not in my code. This is within gleRunVertexSubmitImmediate.

Comment: The index calculation looks wrong. The `i` index should be multiplied by `nz+1`, not the `j` index. But as long as `nx` and `nz` are equal, this shouldn't cause a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be that you're passing `primitiveCount: indices.count` when creating the `SCNGeometryElement` rather than `indices.count/3` (since there are three indices per triangle). I'm surprised there's no earlier bounds checking, but without that, you could certainly see a crash depending on the number of indices.

Comment: **Thank you** this started driving me mad.